# How to pass parameters to action in Flutter

Tags: flutter, action, flutter-redux

I have this action

```
Future<void> signUpAction(Store<AppState> store) async {
  try {
    // ...
  } catch (e) {
    // ..
  }
}
```

And I dispatch it like this

```
store.dispatch(signUpAction);
```

Now, if I want to pass two paramters, how would I do that? Since there is already one parameter there.

I tried this

```
Future<void> signUpAction(Store<AppState> store, email, password) async {
  try {
    // ...
  } catch (e) {
    // ..
  }
}
```

but then on dispatching, if I do

```
store.dispatch(signUpAction("some@email.com", "somEPa55word!"));
```

it says the singUpAction expects 3 parameters, so I don't know very well how to pass only these two

Thank you

Comment: Because your ```signUpAction()``` method needs/required 3 parameters. Make it optional named parameters by adding ```{}``` ```signUpAction({Store<AppState> store, email, password})```,now you can call it by ```(signUpAction(email: "some@email.com", password: "somEPa55word!")```. Here is some good answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/55866881/12789200

Comment: Thank you @Reign, if you want to, you can put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Did that really work? How would the method get the store then?

Comment: @nvoigt, no, it didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispatch method expects a specific signature. If your method does not have exactly that signature, you can make an [anonymous function](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#anonymous-functions) on the fly that matches the signature.

In this case, since your method takes not only the store, but also the email and password:

```
store.dispatch((x) => signUpAction(x, "some@email.com", "somEPa55word!"));
```

Comment: This says Error: Expected ')' before this.
    Redux.store.dispatch(x => signUpAction(x, "some@email.com", "somEPa55word!"));

Comment: @user3808307 Sorry, forgot the brackets.

Comment: It seems to be working but I am having a problem with my action so I can't properly test it, I'll let you know as soon as I fix it, thank you

Comment: Works, I am so sorry I started with Flutter, everything is extremely complicated

Comment: I don't understand what it means that dispatch takes a signature and that that  anonymous method matches the signature.

Comment: When you look at the function definition of `dispatch` you will see that it takes one parameter. That parameter must be a method that takes a store as parameter and returns a Future<void>. Your method looked like that, so you could pass it directly as a parameter. Your new method did not look like that. So you had to first build a method to look like the old one, as far as parameter types and return type goes. That is what `() => ` or `() {}` does, it builds a method on the fly. So `(x) => code;` builds a method that gets an `x` and returns whatever `code` returns.

Comment: I added a documentation link so you can get a better explanation than I can put in a comment here.